# How to check if jwt token user matches the user passed in api url - asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a situation where I want to allow only the user access the api if it's name matches with name in token ,for example ; api/v1/customers/john/address
I have set jwt token configuration in startup.cs and token can be accessed from api/v1/token.  A post request passing username then token is created with username embedded. I want to check in a controller if the url name (john) is in jwt token that was passed in header. Please advise if there is a better way of doing this . There are actually wpf applications users who are consuming these APIs. I want to grant access based on if user in URL matches the token user it was given . Thank you

Comment: How the JWT token is being passed to the API? How the username is passed in the url? These questions you need to answer before you get proper solution. Also you need to share the code of API which involves username.

Comment: Token is passed in the header - Authorisation Bearer + token

Comment: username is passed in the URL api/customers/username/address

Comment: The simple logic is to retrieve username from the URL and token from the header. Compare the username of url with the username from the token and allow if they matches. Create a new class inheriting from `AuthorizeAttribute` class and override `AuthorizeCore` method and implement above logic there. Return `false` from this method when usernames don't match else return `true`

Comment: Thanks , can I do that in the startup.cs or it has to be done in each api controller ?

Comment: In each API controller. You need to read about how to override and use AuthorizeAttribute.